# Enum strings instead of int

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, uisegmentedcontrol

I got a segmented control with 3 options. I didn't really know how to create a variable from the `selected.segmentedIndex` so I copy a method from another place.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int, tipoServidor) {
SERVIDOR_ARG = 1,
SERVIDOR_EU = 2,
SERVIDOR_US = 3};
@property (nonatomic) tipoServidor servidorType;

<Another file>
if (self.persistentSettings.servidorType == SERVIDOR_ARG){
    self.servidorControl.selectedSegmentIndex= 0;
} else if (self.persistentSettings.servidorType == SERVIDOR_EU) {
    self.servidorControl.selectedSegmentIndex= 1;
} else if (self.persistentSettings.servidorType == SERVIDOR_US) {
    self.servidorControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;}

<Another file>
- (NSString *)servidorType {
AdSettings *settings = [[AdSettings alloc] init];

NSString *server = [settings servidorType];
```

The problem is that the last line throws this error:

`Implicit conversion of 'tipoServidor' (aka 'enum tipoServidor') to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC`

How is the correct way to make this work?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the last line throws this error: Implicit conversion of `tipoServidor` (aka `enum tipoServidor`) to `NSString *` is disallowed with ARC

ARC or not, an `enum` is not an `NSString`, so you cannot do it. In order to deal with it, either define an array of strings that represent your `enum` values, or write a small function that does the mapping, for example, like this:

```
NSString *DescriptionOfServidor(tipoServidor e) {
    switch (e) {
        case SERVIDOR_ARG: return @"SERVIDOR_ARG";
        case SERVIDOR_EU: return @"SERVIDOR_EU";
        case SERVIDOR_US: return @"SERVIDOR_US";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

All you need now is this call:

```
NSString *server = DescriptionOfServidor([settings servidorType]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Im trying to think where to put that function DescriptionOfServidor... a last hint? haha

Comment: @user3294339 That depends on where you want to use it. If it is local to a single .m file, put it in that file, above the `@implementation` section of whatever class that you may have there, and add `static` in front of `NSString`. If you want it shared among multiple .m files, put it in a .m class of your choice, and add a forward declaration to the header where the `enum` is declared. Forward declaration looks like this: `NSString *DescriptionOfServidor(tipoServidor e);`

Comment: @user3294339 Try this out. If it works for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Sorry, ignore that last question